# How to make media description show on form view when used as entity reference

Tags: entities, media, 9

Drupal 9...
I have a content type of "Resource" which uses a field "download" which references the media type "document", but when I upload a file to the field, it gives me no opportunity to enter a description for the newly uploaded file.

Resource content type
Field_download  (entity reference to Media Type = Document)

Media Type: Document

- field_description (text  -- required)
- field_media_document (file -- required -- enabled description field)

1 - New Resource content type… upload the media file

[image]

2 - the media upload box appears

[image]

3 - Selected the file I want to upload - it is here that I want to enter the file's description.  The help text even says "Fill in any required fields and save..." but no required field appears.

[image]

4 - Insert the media, now that it has been uploaded

[image]

5 - The new "Resource" node shows the new file, but still no opportunity to enter description

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found the solution:

> If you want to be able to add a new file with a description using Media library then visit
> /admin/structure/media/manage/document/form-display/media_library
> and enable the "Document" field.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2022-08-24/how-to-use-description-when-inlining-link-to-media-documents-d9#comment-14669785